# how can i serialize json response for windows phone?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, serialization

I  am  having  following  Json  response

```
 string Response=  "" {
"category": [
    {
        "biller": [
            {
                "adhocPayment": "Y",
                "billPresentment": "N",
                "billerCategoryId": "05",
                "billerId": "BILLPAYTEST",
                "billerLogo": "#",
                "billerName": "Airtel Chennai",
                "displayLogoName": "#",
                "label1": "CONSUMER NO",
                "label2": "PHONE NO",
                "maxAmount": "10000",
                "minAmount": "10"
            },
            {
                "adhocPayment": "Y",
                "billPresentment": "N",
                "billerCategoryId": "05",
                "billerId": "VODFONE",
                "billerLogo": "#",
                "billerName": "VODOFONE",
                "displayLogoName": "#",
                "label1": "CONSUMER NO",
                "label2": "PHONE NO",
                "maxAmount": "10000",
                "minAmount": "10"
            }
        ],
        "categoryName": "Mobile Recharge",
        "totalRecords": 2
    },
    {
        "biller": [
            {
                "adhocPayment": "N",
                "billPresentment": "N",
                "billerCategoryId": "30",
                "billerId": "SUNTVDTH",
                "billerLogo": "#",
                "billerName": "SUN TV",
                "displayLogoName": "#",
                "label1": "Subscriber ID^10^10^N^N^N",
                "label2": "#",
                "maxAmount": "10000",
                "minAmount": "100"
            }
        ],
        "categoryName": "DTH Recharge",
        "totalRecords": 1
    }
],
"dcid": "01",
"startRecNo": "0001",
"totalRecord": 0,
"txnno": "0211151051285128"
}""
```

to  serialize  it  i am  following

Enclosing  classes

```
 public class RootObject
    {

        public List<Category> category { get; set; }
        public string dcid { get; set; }
        public object startRecNo { get; set; }
        public int totalRecord { get; set; }
        public string txnno { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public List<Biller> biller { get; set; }
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
        public int totalRecords { get; set; }
    }

    public class Biller
    {

        public string adhocPayment { get; set; }
        public string bankCode { get; set; }
        public string billPresentment { get; set; }
        public string billerCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string billerId { get; set; }
        public string billerLogo { get; set; }
        public string billerMnemoName { get; set; }
        public string billerName { get; set; }
        public string delChannelId { get; set; }
        public string label1 { get; set; }
        public string label2 { get; set; }
        public string label3 { get; set; }
        public string label4 { get; set; }
        public string label5 { get; set; }
        public string labelType { get; set; }
        public string maxAmount { get; set; }
        public string minAmount { get; set; }
        public string minimumPayment { get; set; }
        public string recordCount { get; set; }
    }
```

In  button click  event handler iam  serializing  like  this

```
foreach (var nit in rootelement.category)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < nit.biller.Count; i++)
            {
              string b = nit.biller[i].billerName.ToString();
              string c=nit.biller[i].label1.ToString();
            }
        }
```

my requirement  is there  are  two  Labels(label1,label2)  in  response..based  on  that  i  will  create  two textbox  in  design  and  show  them..

number  of  Labels  in  response  is  dynamic,
every  time  it  changes ,how  to  check/get  labels  count from response.
based  on  that  i  need  to  show same  no  of  textbox's in  design..

please  help me  regarding  this..

Comment: Firstly, as it is a string it is already serialized so you are looking to deserialize it. Secondly, you don't need to write this manually as there are several options that will do it for you. .Net existing implementation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx  and external libraries such as: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic collectionWrapper = new
{
    ppp = new RootObject()
    {
        dcid = "01",
        startRecNo = "0001",
        totalRecord = 0,
        txnno = "0211151051285128",
        category = new List<Category> 
        {
            new Category()
            {
                categoryName = "Mobile Recharge",
                totalRecords = 2,
                biller = new List<Biller>
                {
                    new Biller()
                    {                                   
                        adhocPayment="Y",
                        billPresentment="N",
                        billerCategoryId="05",
                        billerId="BILLPAYTEST",
                        billerLogo="#",
                        billerName= "Airtel Chennai",
                        displayLogoName= "#",
                        label1= "CONSUMER NO",
                        label2= "PHONE NO",
                        maxAmount= "10000",
                        minAmount= "10"
                    },
                    ......................
                }
            },
            new Category()
            {
                categoryName = "Mobile Recharge",
                totalRecords = 2,
                biller = new List<Biller>
                {
                    new Biller()
                    {                                   
                        adhocPayment="Y",
                        billPresentment="N",
                        billerCategoryId="05",
                        billerId="BILLPAYTEST",
                        billerLogo="#",
                        billerName= "Airtel Chennai",
                        displayLogoName= "#",
                        label1= "CONSUMER NO",
                        label2= "PHONE NO",
                        maxAmount= "10000",
                        minAmount= "10"
                    }
                }
            },
            ..................... 
        }
    }
};

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize to json and deserialize from JSON. please, avoid doing it "by hand". You can convert your task in a single line of code:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

Al the documentation that you need is [available here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

You can install it in your project as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

In fact, you should be using [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), which allows you to communicate between the device and a server using HTTP and JSON serialization in a very easy way.